# <input type="file"> don't return anything when page is submitted. "Undefined index:"

Tags: php, html

I have done a code in which on submit button click, I get a value from Image selected from , but when I try to get the value from $_POST it is giving me error like : Undefined index:  ....(Though I have selected an image using file input)

Here is the code of HTML Tag I have Placed:

```
<input type="file" name="imgFile" accept="image/*" id="imgFile" />
```

And here is the code from which I m trying to get value on submit button:

```
$img = $_POST['imgFile'];
```

Comment: That's not how you get a file from  post.  `print_r($_FILES)` to see what's there. Also, make sure you are using `<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>`  See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have strict php turned on, which is why your getting the error message. But additionally you are trying to get `$_FILES` data through a `$_POST` command which doesn't work with php. All `type="file"` needs to be taken from `$_FILES` all other POST data comes from `$_POST`.

```
<?php
$img = "";
if(isset($_FILES["imgFile"])){
    $img = $_FILES["imgFile"];
}
```

I recommend that everyone programs in php strict mode instead of disabling it; it will help eliminate confusing bugs in the future.

Comment: Can you explain what strict PHP is?

Comment: no, all HTML file types will be put into `$_FILES` all other post fields will be put into `$_POST`. Strict php basically forces you to use a cleaner format by requireing you to initiate variables and check to see if variables exist before doing something with them. By doing that you code has a much better chance of having less errors, and less silly mistakes.

Comment: Understood. The first line of your answer made me think that disabling strict mode (whatever it is) will make the code work with `$_POST`.

Comment: Your right, that is what the line sounds like thanks for the catch. I reworded it now. I hope that makes better sense

Comment: Thanks, it works. I get the image name by, $img = "";
if(isset($_FILES["imgFile"])){
    $img = $_FILES["imgFile"]['name'];
}

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the variable `$_FILES['imgFile']` instead of `$_POST['imgFile']`.

Answer (score 2):

Files should be accessed through the `$_FILES` super-global, not `$_POST`. So for your example, it'll look something like:

```
$_FILES['imgFile']
```

Also, make sure you've set the relevent `enctype` on the form (i.e. `multipart/form-data`).